# Constructor for '' must explicitly initialize the reference member ''

Tags: c++, reference, member

I have this class

```
class CamFeed {
public:
    // constructor
    CamFeed(ofVideoGrabber &cam); 
    ofVideoGrabber &cam;

};
```

And this constructor:

```
CamFeed::CamFeed(ofVideoGrabber &cam) {
    this->cam = cam;
}
```

I get this error on the constructor:
**Constructor for '' must explicitly initialize the reference member ''**

What is a good way to get around this?

Comment: You must initialize a reference immediately because it cannot be null like a ptr

Comment: Think carefully about what this line of code means, it's not what you think: `this->cam = cam;` This wouldn't re-target the reference. It would call `operator=` on `this->cam` -- which hasn't been initialized yet.

Answer (score 68):

You need to use the constructor initializer list:

```
CamFeed::CamFeed(ofVideoGrabber& cam) : cam(cam) {}
```

This is because references must refer to something and therefore cannot be default constructed. Once you are in the constructor body, all your data members have been initialized. Your `this->cam = cam;` line would really be an assignment, assigning the value referred to by `cam` to whatever `this->cam` refers to.